# My client need to send mailing lists, can server black listed as spam?

Tags: spam, email-spam, mailing-list, mailing, acymailing

My client need to send 500 or 1000 e-mails to **a list of registered members that subscribe to mailing list**, can I marked as spammer and have problems with my shared ip blacklisted on spam lists or spammer in gmail, yahoo, outlook?

What the best way to send these e-mails from my server without risks of being marked as spam or get my ip black listed? Or I recommend them to not do that in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No

You can send an email to 1000 different users. A lot of companies send millions of emails per month !

## It first depends on your users

**Users can mark the email as spam** if you send it without their mutual consent or send 1000 mails to each, obviously !
But in your question **you explain that your users have given their consent** because they are subscribed to your mailing list, **so thats good**.

## Secondly it depends on your mail content

**It depends mainly on your mail content**.
There are a plenty of different reasons that your content can be marked as spam.

- some word in subject
- the ratio text/image of your content (too much images can be consider as spam by mail client)

There are a lot of words which can marked your mail as spam by the mail client.
a non exhaustive words list : https://blog.hubspot.com/blog/tabid/6307/bid/30684/the-ultimate-list-of-email-spam-trigger-words.aspx

## In a lot of cases, emailing services can be very useful

**You can use service like MailChimp or SendGrid** to send huge amount of emails. They have free tier plan to try their service.

e.g with SendGrid

> Send up to 40,000 emails for the first 30 days and 100 emails per day free forever

with MailChimp

> Forever Free
> Up to 2,000 subscribers and 12,000 emails per month

Moreover they have a nicely done dashboard with a lot of information about your sent emails (**spam report**, devices, clicked mails, opened mails etc..)

## Last recommendation

You can use a service different for your marketing mails and your transactional emails. So marketing emails don't impact the reputation of your transactional emails (they are more important than marketing mails)

Comment: Its about one e-mail to 500 up to 1000 users (emails). Only a newsletter, not more than 2 emails in month to the same user/email.

Comment: Yeah don't worry ! It's fine ! But as i suggested you, try to use a different service for your marketting emails / transactional emails. Marketing emails are obviously more reported as spam than transactional emails. So it avoid to lower your reputation of transactional emails.

Thanks @travis for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a third party API (SendGrid, MailChimp etc.) to send out those emails. Using a 3rd party API sends the emails directly to your audience's inbox and not to their junk or spam box.

However, if you are sending mail which is spam and people are marking those emails as spam, your reputation with that mailing service will go down.

There are many "bulk email" service providers out there. You would want to google and research your options as each one of them have their own emailing price plans.